# Can the bq CLI list only views and exclude tables?

Tags: google-cloud-sdk, bq

Listing the views is as simple as:

```sh
bq ls project_id:dataset_id
```

This includes both views *and* tables. Is there a way to filter this to *only* show views? The `--filter` parameter only appears to work on datasets and transfer jobs.

References:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_ls
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/listing-views

Comment: can you simply grep the output? 
bq ls project_id:dataset_id | grep "VIEW"

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

- Querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS (google will bill you minimum 10GiB):

  ```sql
  SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM `PROJECT_NAME`.dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS ;
  ```
- Using the `bq` utility in combination with grep or awk:

  ```sh
  bq ls __dataset__ | grep -i VIEW
  ```

  or with awk looking at the second column:

  ```sh
  bq ls __dataset__ | awk '{ if($2 == "VIEW"){ print $1; } }'
  ```